# How to deal with histogram zero count when computing image entropy?

Tags: python, matlab, entropy

I am trying to implement the Matlab function [`entropy()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/entropy.html) in Python.

> Entropy
>
> Entropy is a statistical measure of randomness that can be used to characterize the texture of the input image.
>
> Entropy is defined as -sum(p.*log2(p)), where p contains the normalized histogram counts returned from imhist.

I use openCV to get the normalized histogram counts. What should I do if there are zeroes in the histogram counts?

Comment: Whoever downvotes this problem please leave a comment, so I can improve my future questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are porting the function into another programming framework, a good answer to your question, in my opinion, would be: *"the same thing that Matlab does"*.

Matlab drops counts equal to `0` before normalizing the histogram. If you open the original function using the command `open entropy`, you will find what you are looking for into its code:

```
% calculate histogram counts
p = imhist(I(:));

% remove zero entries in p 
p(p==0) = [];

% normalize p so that sum(p) is one.
p = p ./ numel(I);

E = -sum(p.*log2(p));
```

Answer (score 1):

There are generally two approaches used in practice that I'm aware of:

- The first one is dropping these counts (i.e. setting "0*log(0) = 0")
- The second one is adding a some small value `e` to every count: `p -> p+e` and renormalizing.